# Shell Script filter Output Value

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I want to filter the output of "docker network ls". My command with output

```
# docker network ls | grep "nw-MariaDB"
a29be99ba348        maindb_nw-MariaDB   bridge              local
```

What can I do if I only want to output maindb_nw-MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following :

```
docker network ls --filter name=nw-MariaDB --format "{{.Name}}"
```

Explanation :

- `--filter name=...` allows us to restrict the output of `docker network ls` to network whose name contain a specific keyword
- `--format` allows us to have each line only return the name of the network